# Create a new html file using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to create a new html file that will be displayed and saved on the server for future use when a new user logs into their account. Can this be done using JavaScript or are there any libraries that I could get that would be able to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done through use of the fs module in node.  See https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html.

However, it is very likely that this is not the best solution to the problem your solving.  Instead of creating a new html file for every user, you probably want to save user details in a database and have a single html file that can be populated with the data when it's needed.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with JavaScript alone unless you use Node.js. Otherwise will need PHP or a similar server-side language.

If you go that route, here is a nice tutorial that may be beneficial to you: 
http://tutorialzine.com/2011/05/generating-files-javascript-php/

Comment: I was not aware of that. I will edit my response.